# Define Analytics Goals in BigQuery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to get Analytics goal conversions and goal names with BigQuery, but it seems this must by defined by myself. How can I define this in BigQuery? Could someone provide me with a query example or guide?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goals configured inside of Google Analytics are not stored in BigQuery and will need to be computed from scratch.

You will need to make a query based on the fact that the goal is generate it is, for example, by event or thank you page, so you need to recreate the calculation of the same according to how you have configured them in Google Analytics Admin section.

Comment: Thanks so much Michele for you answer, now I get the point on this issue. It seems feasible for most-all of my goals.