# How to query goals(goal1 and goal7) with date, source, medium, keyword in big query from Google Analytics data?

Tags: sql, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have written the following query:

```
SELECT date, 
       trafficsource.source, 
       trafficsource.medium, 
       trafficsource.keyword, 
       trafficsource.campaign, 
       trafficsource.adcontent, 
       ( 
              SELECT x.value 
              FROM   Unnest(hit.customdimensions) x 
              WHERE  x.index = 9) AS dimension_9 
FROM   `tfa-big-query.******.ga_sessions_*`, 
       unnest(hits) AS hit 
WHERE  date BETWEEN '20180101' AND    '20181014' limit 1000
```

I am getting the data for mentioned columns in the above query.

But in the above query I do not know where to find Goals (Goal1 and Goal7) and bring them together in one table.

How can I know where to query for the Goal columns in Google Analytics data ?

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define Analytics Goals in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814678/define-analytics-goals-in-bigquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goals are not in GA bigquery. You'll need to calculate them yourself.